# gingerbread randomly restarts activities

Tags: android, android-activity, restart, ram, android-2.3-gingerbread

I feel like this is a memory issue on Gingerbread devices, but after a few activities - whether those activities are `finish()`ed or not - the screen goes white and an activity reloads, I'm never sure which activity in the stack will get revealed or closed after the white screen goes away.

Similarly, when this happens, after the app exits the launcher screen has to reload.

No error message gets posted to logcat, no force close.

I've monitored resources in logcat but I haven't pinpointed anything dire.

I've seen this on devices with 512mb RAM, but since applications don't get that amount of resources, its tough to say where the issue is, if it is a memory issue at all

insight appreciated

Comment: So what is the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another possible reason for this behavior on Gingerbread could be the constant defined in `com.android.server.am.ActivityStack`:

```
// How long until we reset a task when the user returns to it.  Currently
// 30 minutes.
static final long ACTIVITY_INACTIVE_RESET_TIME = 1000*60*30;
```

> *...the screen goes white and an activity reloads*

During an activity's transition from background to foreground state, its duration of inactivity is compared with this constant. In some of the cases, the activity is reloaded (more on this below).

> *I'm never sure which activity in the stack will get revealed or closed
>   after the white screen goes away*

The flags set for the activity are used to determine which activity from the stack will be shown. The method that determines this is `ActivityStack#resetTaskIfNeededLocked(ActivityRecord, ActivityRecord)`. You can look at it here: [Link](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/gingerbread-release/services/java/com/android/server/am/ActivityStack.java).

You may find it interesting to go through `ActivityStack` class and see how an activity launch/resume is handled, and how an activity stack is rearranged when required.

Note that the constant mentioned above holds the value `zero` on version 4.0.1_r1 and higher, and is not put to use.

Even if you are noticing this behavior for activities launched and resumed within 30 minutes, the flags may still be responsible for reshuffling of the stack.

> *No error message gets posted to logcat, no force close.*

Killing of a process due to low memory is registered in Logcat. So, I doubt its that.

Comment: how do you avoid this? is there a way I can override this behavior?

Comment: @CQM In the method I mentioned above, a check is performed to see if `ActivityInfo.FLAG_ALWAYS_RETAIN_TASK_STATE` is set, before setting `forceReset` to true. So, you should be able to avoid this by adding `android:alwaysRetainTaskState="true"` to your activity in the manifest. Here's what it does: [Link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#always).